# White label/reseller eCommerce providers?

Tags: content-management-system, portal

I'm looking for companies that allow white labeling/reselling of portals/CMS that are focused on ecommerce, or could be configured to include ecommerce.

A possible example is a company that provides white labeling of Drupal with Ubercart.

We have two service offerings we are looking at providing based on white label providers.

**1) Our company is a service provider assisting the client to create an individual site**

Our company *assists* client in creating a portal/site for their offerings on **our** branded site,(our site would use the while label service as well) but ideally, the client site could be branded for the client.  (this is probably subject to the platform that is being offered by the white label provider)

**2) Our company is a reseller of the white label service, under our brand**

Our company *resells* the white label services, with our company adding value. Client gets their own instance, under their brand.

On the tech side we are looking to benefit from someone else dealing with version upgrades, availability, scalability etc; hence the research on white label providers.

#### Update

To be clear I'm looking for a company to deal with all of the infrastructure side of things; including the software.

Comment: [Don't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46035/should-i-remove-tags-that-dont-contribute-to-categorizing-the-question/46037#46037) [tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43879/anti-tags-valid-use-or-not) [nonprogramming.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/can-we-disallow-the-use-of-belongs-on-xxxxxxx-and-not-programming-related-tag/10222#10222)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into this on and off, I'm discovered there doesn't seem to be a lot of 'white label ecommerce' offerings under that title.  However, there are applications like Magento that support multisite with theme's.  Presumably you can create a full sub domain and skin it to brand it.

This approach may or may not be a good fit though.  One particular functionality that seems to be missing is the ability to allow self registration and create of a site.  This to me is the holy grail of white lableing.  The closest I've come to that functionality is Aegir in the Drupal ecosystem or Drupal Commons with it's organic groups.

However, the situation is different for white label social networking.  This seems like a much more mature industry.  Perhaps the approach is to use social networking white labeling with an ecommerce plug in.

Bottom line is that I haven't found a turn key platform that allows a power user level of functionality.  Hopefully it will come about soon!